# Sorting a particular column of datatable of string type that contains numeric data

Tags: c#

I have a datatable (.Net) with multiple columns. One of the columns say RollNo is of string type but contains numeric data. Eg. **1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14**. I am trying to sort using the following:

```
string sql = 
  "Select StudentID, RollNo, AdmissionID,(FirstName + Space(1) + Isnull(MiddleName,'') + Space(1) + Isnull(LastName,'')) as Name," +
  " PermState as State from Students where ClassId  = '" + ddlClass.SelectedValue + "'" +
  " order by RollNo";

DataTable dt = bl.GetDataSet(sql);       
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "RollNo";
```

But after sorting I get the result as **1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.**

How to solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Linq-To-DataSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx) and cast the `string` to `int`:

```
DataTable ordered = dt.AsEnumerable()
                      .OrderBy(r => int.Parse(r.Field<String>("RollNo")))
                      .CopyToDataTable();
```

<sub>You need to add a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll` and `using System.Linq;`</sub>

Note that you can omit the `CopyToDataTable` if you don't need it, i've showed it just to demonstrate how to get a `DataTable` from the `IEnumerable<DataRow>`.

Comment: Fantastic! Tim, Thanks for your support. But what if RollNo field also contains alphanumeric data along with numeric?

Comment: That depends on the format. In general `Regex` is your friend. You can use any kind of code in Linq.

Comment: I need sample data to know how to sort that numerically. But that would be out of scope of this question anyway, because it would a a `Regex` question. I would ask another question "How to get a number out of this string".

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it if your DB is large. You have to either make "string to numeric" conversion in your sql statement(that means on the DB server), which is costly, or have to read all the table to memory and make this sort there which is also costly.

I would create a new numeric field(column) and make this conversion once as a batch process.

Answer (score 0):

```
        DataTable dt = GetData();
        dt.Columns.Add("RollNo1", typeof(Int32));
        foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
        {
            item["RollNo1"] = item["RollNo"];
        }
        dt.DefaultView.Sort = "RollNo1";
        dt.Columns.Remove("RollNo");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```